# Console.log resolver data in graphql

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to console.log the resolver in a graphql app. The graphiql part works (I can start the server and see the graphql dashboard and then use the root query to retrieve the results in the browser pane), but I'm unable to console.log the same results in my browser console. Following is my code:

```
const GetBooks = {
 type: new GraphQLList(BookTypes),
 args: {},
 resolve() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let sql = singleLineString`
        select * from books
        `;
        sql = mysql.format(sql);
        pool.query(sql, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(results);
            console.log(resolve(results));
        });
    });
   }
 };
```

The part that is 'not working' is the console.log(resolve(results)) part of the code. Can someone point out why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

The `console.log` you are using is not on the client side.

It logs the result on the server side, not on the browser. Check your command line that started the GraphQL server, the logs should be there.

Comment: I thought so too but the command line is not outputting the console.log either; I'm able to see other console.log messages that I have set up in index.js and schema.js, but no output from the query file, even though the graphiql dashboard works!

Comment: I am in the exact same situation, did you solve this ?

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte anyone figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @DanMandel My workaround was to throw as an Error and pick it up on the browser. But I only needed to do it once so I'm not going to hunt for the bug.

Comment: The question code above is on the server side. `select * from.. ` is server code. My best guess is that graphql either overrides the `console object` somehow - or is run in another `child-process` - and the `console.log ..` happens on the child process... so we can't see anything on the parent process. And the `standard error stream` is captured, and send to the browser.. that's why you can see a `throw Error` inside the `resolver` in the browser - but no exception shows up in the `main process`. This is how they prevent the `main process` form crashing also - and let the client know about it.